# C++ extended switch for any class

Tags: c++11, macros

Was thinking about extending the C switch beyond integers. Here is what it came to - will gladly accept any suggestions for improvement.
Note: "Any class" in the title is not quite correct - the class should have equal operator and hash function to be used in this switch.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
using xmap = std::unordered_map<T, std::function<void()>>;

template<typename T>
void xwitch(const T& var, const xmap<T>& m, std::function<void()> otherwise = []() {})
{
    auto it = m.find(var);
    if (it == m.end())
        otherwise();
    else
        it->second();
}

#define SWITCH(var) xwitch(var, xmap<std::remove_const<decltype(str)>::type> {
#define END_SWITCH });
#define CASE {
#define THEN , []() {
#define END_CASE } },
#define DEFAULT }, []() {

int main()
{
    const std::string str{ "Second string" };
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    SWITCH(str)
        CASE "First string"s THEN std::cout << "First string matched\n"; END_CASE
        CASE "Second string"s THEN std::cout << "Second string matched\n"; END_CASE
        CASE "Third string"s THEN std::cout << "Third string matched\n"; END_CASE
    END_SWITCH
    
    SWITCH("unmatched"s)
        CASE "First string"s THEN std::cout << "First string matched\n"; END_CASE
        CASE "Second string"s THEN std::cout << "Second string matched\n"; END_CASE
        CASE "Third string"s THEN std::cout << "Third string matched\n"; END_CASE
        DEFAULT std::cout << "No matches\n";
    END_SWITCH
}
```

Comment: Technically this doesn't work on any class, since it requires the keys to implement `operator==` and `std::hash<T>(...)`. But your question is valid regardless.

Comment: Why use macros? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdad77d62fe85c84

Answer (score 3):

## Design

I don't think I'd use these macros in production, but it seems like a useful tool for thinking about a proposal for how a more general C++ `switch` might be implemented.

One improvement that could be made is to fall back to `std::map` if `std::unordered_map` can't be used (for totally-ordered unhashable objects).

One disadvantage we have compared to a solution at language level is that the map is constructed dynamically each time the `SWITCH()` is reached, rather than requiring the map to be `constexpr` and populating it during compilation.  I don't see any easy way to rectify that.  (I guess some users might consider this a feature, in that the cases can be computed at run-time, but I would prefer a visible map object for those.)

A serious weakness is that local variables aren't available to the code, because they are not captured in the lambdas.  We might want to define `THEN` as `, [&]{` to address that (I removed the unnecessary `()`, too).

---

## Code

- Missing include `<type_traits>`
- In `SWITCH()` the type `decltype(str)` ought to be `decltype(var)`.
- `<iostream>` and `<string>` shouldn't be needed until `main()` - it's worth deferring them to show what's actually needed by `SWITCH()`.

Comment: He can work around the dynamic construction by storing the value in a local variable, then constructing the map as `static`, and then invoking it.  https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30d3a96dda0fa53c

Comment: Thanks, Toby, I do think it'll be best as the language-level improvement.  As for compile-time map, I tried making it a template class with operator (), but it was way more complicated.

Comment: Just checked - works fine without explicitly including type_traits.  Well, at least in Visual Studio.

Comment: Relying on things working without including the documented headers is a big portability risk (even to future versions of the same compiler).  I recommend including headers that the standard says you need, rather than playing fast and loose like that.